# Simultaneous Thread running

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to run a simulation of negotiation between few people (lets say 6).
The negotiation is in pairs, meaning in this case: 3 simultaneous negotiation.

I thought of running 3 threads (neg1.run(), neg2.run(), neg3.run()), but the thing is I want to run them again afterwards once a negotiation is over, and they are free to negotiate again.
This has to be using a thread because few parameters are being changed during the negotiation and I need to have the most updated value of them.

I thought of creating a queue of negotiators that once one of them is finished with the run, he will return to the queue and wait for another "call".

Problem is, i'm not sure how to handle the recalling of a negotiation (launching another thread).

Comment: Declare "Negotiation" as a `Runnable`, then create your thread `new Thread(new Negotation()).start()`

Comment: This is the first running, but its more complex than this, since I run 3 of these, and I need to re-run it few more times until I can't run it again (after all the negotiators stopped working due to some factors)

Comment: can you write up some pseudo code or something, im not 100% sure I am following. Your idea of a queue with runnables in them makes sense but I dont follow the "recalling" of them sense launching a new thread is as simple as creating a new thread with a (new or reused) runnable. Or even just calling `Thread.start` one more time

Comment: 1. Random 2 negotiators from list of negotiators
2. Negotiate
3. once ended - try to arrange another negotiation between 2 free negotiators (if the negotiation failed for reason - fire one of them based on few parameters - meaning he is not able to negotiate again)
4. if only one negotiator left eventually end the running of the program.

Answer (score 0):

here's a quick and dirty version. I'm open to suggestions and criticism and will edit it accordingly (or you edit it if you want). Maybe I am creating too many threads?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>(6);
    personList.add(new Person("George"));
    personList.add(new Person("John"));
    personList.add(new Person("Mary"));
    personList.add(new Person("Linda"));
    personList.add(new Person("William"));
    personList.add(new Person("Albert"));

    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors
            .newFixedThreadPool(personList.size() / 2);

    while (true) {
        if (executor.getActiveCount() < executor.getMaximumPoolSize()) {
            executor.execute(new Negotiation(personList));
        } else {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}

}
```

---

```
public class Person {
String name;
String lastContact = "";
boolean busy;

public Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public synchronized boolean approach() {
    if (!busy) {
        return busy = true;
    } else
        return false;
}

public synchronized boolean leave() {
    if (busy) {
        busy = false;
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public String getLastContact(){
    return lastContact;
}

public void setLastContact(String partnerName){
    lastContact = partnerName;
}

}
```

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class Negotiation implements Runnable {
Random rand = new Random();
ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>(6);
Person convStarter;
Person convPartner;

public Negotiation(ArrayList<Person> personList) {
    this.personList = personList;
}

private Person findPerson(ArrayList<Person> personList) {
    long seed = System.nanoTime();
    Collections.shuffle(personList, new Random(seed));
    for (Person person : personList) {
        if (person.approach()) {
            return person;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        if ((convStarter = findPerson(personList)) != null) {
            if ((convPartner = findPerson(personList)) != null) {
                if (!convStarter.getLastContact().equals(
                        convPartner.getName())) {
                    System.out.println(convStarter.getName()
                            + " is talking to " + convPartner.getName());
                    convStarter.setLastContact(convPartner.getName());
                    convPartner.setLastContact(convStarter.getName());
                    Thread.sleep(randInt(2000, 10000));  //your actual negotiation
                    System.out.println(convStarter.getName()
                            + " stopped talking to "
                            + convPartner.getName());
                }
                convPartner.leave();
            }
            convStarter.leave();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public int randInt(int min, int max) {
    return rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create "Negotiation" as a Runnable. And create a thread pool of 3 threads using java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.

Whenever you want to negotiate just call threadpoolexector.execute(). If any thread is available to carry negotiation. It will be done. Else pool will throw exception  RejectedExecutionException . That will tell you that no thread is available to carry negotiation.

Try this `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`. It might help what you want to achieve.